# Swift does not see the variable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to pass variable into

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6 // <-- HERE
}
```

from the

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { ... }
```

for it I do the next:

```
class GalleryController: UIViewController {
    var galleryCount = 0 as Int
}
```

and later in the

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var gallery = myJSON["result"][choosenRow]["gallery"]
    galleryCount = gallery.count
}
```

I override my galleryCount variable and when I want to use it in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return galleryCount // <-- HERE
}
```

I get the error: `error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'galleryCount' galleryCount`

Why? I do not understand this error. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Why would you cast the variable to an `Int` instead of declaring it as such? `var galleryCount: Int = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define variable without value

```
class GalleryController: UIViewController {
    var galleryCount:Int = 0
}
```

And initialize its value in `viewDidLoad`

because the first method which is called in collection delegate is `numberOfItemsInSection` not `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

### EDIT

First method which is called is `numberOfItemsInSection` so the `galleryCount` will stay 0 and your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` never called.

If you want to use `galleryCount` then do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Ok, but in this case when I initialize `galleryCount = gallery.count` in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {` it prints `use of unresolved identifier galleryCount`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade First method which is called is `numberOfItemsInSection` so the `galleryCount` will stay 0 and your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` never called.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade If you want to use galleryCount then do it in view did load.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade. Try this solution. I agree with him.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Brother, You have added all the thing in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` you have to add it in `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade You try to get data in `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`. This is a wrong way. You need call webservice when you need it. And `update` to `UI` when it `finished`. `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` this function only run when your application receive memory warning.

Comment: @longpham oh, sorry! My fail! Just a minute

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade You declare as `Optional Value`. In `Run time` actually 'galleryCount' has yet be created. Try with `var galleryCount:Int = 0`

Comment: @longpham no, it does not help me, too =/ the same error here

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade This code look can be run now. Clear your project and run again.

Comment: @@OrkhanAlizade cheer. Remove `return 6` in your code. Replace by `return self. galleryCount`